# Delete numbers from array

Tags: java, android, arrays, string

I got an `ArrayList` "ArrayList1" with content like

```
0090113itemone ,
1000120itemtwo ,
0090113itemthree
```

There are always 7 numbers in front of an item .

Now I want to remove the numbers to assign only the items to a `ListView`.
I tried to convert the `Array` to `String` with

```
String[] arr = ArrayList1.toArray(new String[ArrayList1.size()]);
```

and then use `substring` to cut the first 7 positions from the string

```
result.append(arr.substring(0,7));
```

But this will get me an error **Cannot invoke substring(int, int) on the array type String[]**

So I would need a way to get rid of these numbers. Either how to solve this error or, if you got a better idea, I'm also open to that.

Comment: `result.append(arr.substring(0,7));` substring(int,int) over an array?  Didn't it through any compilation error? You should iterate through the string array and do a substring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error "Cannot invoke **substring(int, int)** on the array type **String[]**" means that the method does not work on this type of object.

It works on a String though.

You don't need to create an Array out of your ArrayList like this:

```
String[] arr = ArrayList1.toArray(new String[ArrayList1.size()]);
```

Instead, use your ArrayList right away. I highly recommend renaming it to Java Camel Case: "arrayList1" to avoid confusion with classes. Use Regex to replace numbers in a String. Try running this for-loop:

```
for (String item : arrayList1) {
    String result = item.replaceAll("[0-9]","");
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to iterate over the array and do it for every string, because `substring()` is a method of the string class and not of the array class. The errormessage **Cannot invoke substring(int, int) on the array type String[]** tell you that you try do build a substring of an Stringarray.

change:

```
result.append(arr.substring(0,7));
```

to:

```
result.append(arr[0].substring(0,7));
```

and put in in a for-loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i<arr.length(); i++)
    result.append(arr[i].substring(0,7));
```

Comment: Now I get an error when I try to put it in the ListView on:

'ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, result);
lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);'

**The constructor ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity, int, StringBuilder) is undefined**

Comment: because you try to put the stringbuilder into an string list. convert the stringbuilder to an string with StringBuilder.toString()

Comment: Only change the error to **The constructor ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity, int, String) is undefined**

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i=0;i<arr.length;i++) {
   arr[i] = arr[i].substring(7);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop through your ArrayList to start with.
Then at least two options you have:

**1)** Use the String.replace method.

```
String x = str.replaceAll("\\d", "");
```

Call this method on each string from your ArrayList.
 
Then handle the x which you get as you need.

**2)** But if your strings may contain digits after their  
 
position 7 and you want those digits included, then loop  
 
through the strings and do:

```
String x = str.substring(7);
```

Then do what you need with x.

Answer (score 0):

Do like this

```
for (String s:arr) {
    result.append(s.replaceAll("\\d",""));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
for (String s:arr) {
    result.append(s.substring(7,s.length()));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to edit each element before copying it. I'd recoment the following:

```
List<String> newList = new ArrayList<>();    
for (String element : arrayList1)
{
  String elementWithoutNumber = element.subString(7);
  newList.add(elementWithoutNumber);
}
String[] arr = ArrayList1.toArray(new String[newList.size()]);
```